# Can the null hypothesis for a t-test be based on values from the sample data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

When forming the null and alternative hypotheses, are we able to use data from the sample?

For example, say we sent marketing materials to two groups. We want to know if the difference in Revenue per Buyer outweighs the difference in Cost per Buyer.

So we set up the following hypotheses:

Null: H_0 = (Group A Revenue per Buyer - Group B Revenue per Buyer) = (Group A Cost per Buyer - Group B Cost per Buyer)
Where Cost/Buyer is the total cost of the campaign divided by # of Buyers.

Alternative: The above equation is not equal

Is this allowed, since we need to look at the sample data to determine the Cost per Buyer (since we don't know the number of Buyers before looking at the sample)? I always assumed the underlying null distribution can't be centered around a value taken from the sample data, as this introduces bias.

Comment: A null hypothesis that the difference in average cost between the two groups is equal to the difference in average revenue does not look as if it is based on the sample data.

Comment: If you have revenue and cost for each individual, you could look at the difference between these (call it profit for that individual) and consider the difference in the average profit per buyer in the two groups (it may reduce the standard errors).  You are in effect testing whether this difference is 0